# diffrent views across browsers kin my React App

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, cross-browser

My website looks different from Chrome mobile view to Safari with an actual phone.
I have used prefixes for all my styles (WebKit,...)
I have also used normalize.css to fix any issue
I need help with that.
I am trying to make my website look the same on all browsers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In common, problems with cross-browser optimization are usually related to different css engines. I advice you to check your CSS in '[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?!)'.

Another thing to check is the viewport param. You should have a look at index.html (yourProject/public/index.html). There should be a meta tag with the "viewport" attribute. Like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

If the tag is on the place, try to ask for help here in each issue.